# Subgroups of cyclic groups with same order

Tags: group-theory

Let $C$ be a cyclic group. Let $A$ and $B$ be two subgroups of $C$ with $|A|=|B|$. Then $A = B$.

How to show this? Thanks.

(Btw, I already know $A$ and $B$ are cyclic)

Comment: This will only hold if $C$ is a finite cyclic group. E.g., $|2\mathbb Z| = |4\mathbb Z|$ but these subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ groups are not equal.

Comment: @amWhy, of course if one reformulates the question in terms of *indices*, then it works for the infinite cyclic group as well.

Comment: I agree, @AndreasCaranti

Answer (score 5):

> Theorem 1: If $G=\langle a\rangle$ be a finite group of order $n$ and $$d_1,d_2,...,d_k$$ be all distinct positive divisors of $n$ so the following subgroups are all the proper distinct subgroups of $G$: $$\langle a^{d_1}\rangle,\langle a^{d_2}\rangle,...,\langle a^{d_k}\rangle $$
>
> Theorem 2: If $G=\langle a\rangle$ be an infinite group  then the following subgroups are all the proper distinct subgroups of $G$: $$\langle e_G\rangle,\langle a\rangle,\langle a^{2}\rangle,...,\langle a^{k}\rangle,... $$

Comment: +1 Nice to have stated explicitly the theorem we're looking at!

Comment: Where can I find the proofs of these theorems?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** As amWhy noted you need $C$ to be finite, so you can assume $C = \mathbb Z/n$ for some $n$.  Let $a$ be the least positive integer contained in $A$.  Show that $a \mid n$ and consequently $a$ generates $A$.  Then $a = n/|A|$ is uniquely identified by the size of $A$, therefore $A$ is uniquely identified by it's size.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for every divisor of the order of a cyclic group $\exists$ a unique subgroup of that order. Now if $A$ and $B$ are two subgroups of a finite cyclic group $G$ then their orders must be divisors of the order of the group and due to uniqueness they must be the same.

Comment: I think the question would be boringly trivial if the OP knew/could use this theorem...

Comment: i agree :) @donantonio